# How to get a User to choose a uno card by cardCode, and not by index. EG: 1 - You picked Red 1

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

My question is how to get a User to choose uno card by cardCode, and not by index.

This game of uno contains number, colour and cardCode - user is to choose a card to play by cardCode 1-41,

The games runs fine when the user chooses the card by index, however when tying to get the user to enter the cardCode  Struggling with searching for the index of the specified card code in player Array-list hand.
Card ArrayList contains number, colour and cardCode.I hope this question is clear enough!

Thank you in advance

````
``int choice = 0; //The index of the card the user picks
            try {
                choice = askForInput();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            if (choice == -1) { //User wants to draw a card
                user.addToHand(deck1.drawCard());
                System.out.println("You drew a card!");
                upNext = checkNextPlayer();
                computersPlay();
    
            } else if (choice == -2) { //User wants to quit
                winner = "No one";
                try {
                    in2.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("You quit!");
                return;
    
            } else { //User wants to play a card
    
                if (!validInput(user, choice)) {
                    userTurn();
                } else {
    
                    centerCard = user.getCard(choice);
                    user.removeFromHand(choice);
                    System.out.println("You played: " + centerCard);
    
    **
    //Think the issue is calling index and not passing a card?
    
HAND CLASS
         * Shows the card at that index in your hand without removing it
         */
        public Card getCard(int index)
        {
            return pHand.get(index);
        }
    
    ```
````

Comment: Is it something that cannot be done by iterating through the ArrayList of Card and find the correct one with an check ?
If yes, then better to use Map instead of array list and override the hashCode and equals method using cardCode in Card class to make it faster.

Comment: Hi to clarify there are 3 ArrayLists playerHand, deck and topPile, First card

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
public Card getCard(int index)         
{             
return pHand.get(index);         
}
```

If you change it to

```
public Card getCard(int cardCode){             
    for(Card card: pHand) {               
        if(cardCode == card.getCardCode().intValue()){
          return card;             
        }         
    }
 return null;         
}
```

This will return the `Card` with matching `cardCode`.
To optimise this code  you can make `pHand` a `Map`.
`Map<Integer,Card> pHand ;` Where the key would be the `cardCode`;